# blazor web assembly service object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Im building some solution in blazor wasm and i need to get some userinfo from my api BEFORE initialload of any page.

so i have service like

```
public class UserService
{
    private readonly HttpClient http;
    private User u;

    public User User
    {
        get { return u; }
        set { u = value; }
    }

    public UserService(HttpClient http)
    {
        this.http = http;
        try
        {
            GetUser();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.u = null;
            Console.WriteLine("UserService Ctor failed to get user from api except:" + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private async void GetUser()
    {
        string endpoint = "user/getuser";
        this.u = await this.http.GetFromJsonAsync<User>(endpoint);
    }
}
```

}

in startup.cs

```
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<UserService>(new UserService(new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) }) );
```

in index

```
  @if (this.u != null && u.User.Login != null ){ @U.User.Login}


[Inject]
private UserService u { get; set; }
```

and when i run i get

```
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
  Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  ..... line 9 so this with null username
```

so i assume that this render is before this userService is instantiated... how should i handle this to wait with any rendering until this initial load in UserService ctor is done ?

Comment: Does the error disappear when not calling the user service during rendering, e. g. from a button click handler?

Comment: Btw: Blazor has a default HTTP instance you can use, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly#default-services)

Comment: yes when i do this on btn click it is ok

Comment: Try checking `User` for null or use null-conditional operators. Your async method sets `User` property later after initialization, or it can fail and never set it, and you will never know about it because method is `async void`.

Comment: You can put your code into `OnInitializedAsync()` method and change signature of `async void GetUser()` to `async Task GetUser()` or `async Task<User> GetUser()`

Comment: I known But i would need to do this in every component. I does not known witch url will be firstly executed. This login is just simplest example

Comment: This is a design issue that may be a sign of even greater issues with your code. Reevaluate your current design and avoid calling async void members at all, let alone in your constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok thanks all
i did it like

```
        UserService u = new UserService(new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
        await u.GetUser();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<UserService>(u);
```

this way is fine and ctor is simple

```
  public UserService(HttpClient http)
    {
        this.http = http;
    }

    public async Task GetUser()
    {
        string endpoint = "user/getuser";
        this.u = await this.http.GetFromJsonAsync<User>(endpoint);
    }
```

is there a better way?
i known that i can use `AuthenticationStateProvider` but i didnt wanted to go this way